# Leave Page Stay On Page With Custom Message

Tags: javascript, onbeforeunload

I am trying to put some custom text on the popup that asks for leave page or stay on the page.
I tried this

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
             return "This is my custom message";
         };
```

But Mozilla and Chrome still says their own messages while IE shows my message.
So what I am trying to do is it should show my custom message with Leave and Stay buttons.
And I am sure I have seen in some webiste although I don't remember which website :(

Is it possible?

Comment: Chrome shows your message first and a general message beneath it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firefox 4 and higher will not show your custom message. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5398788/58107):

> From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload):
>
> > Note that in Firefox 4 and later the returned string is not displayed to the user. See Bug [588292](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=588292).
>
> This "Bug" is actually a (imho questionable) feature.. so there's no way to display the message in Firefox 4. If you think it should be changed, comment on that bug so the Firefox developers will know that people actually want to be able to show a custom string.