# Greasemonkey alert to confirm closing window not working?

Tags: javascript, firefox, greasemonkey

I'm working on what should be a simple Greasemonkey script to confirm that you want to close the window if you have a lengthy message typed.

I had a working version of this script a few years back, but the website it worked for has undergone changes, so I'm hoping to fix it. However, I can't even get a simple confirmation to work:

```
function confirmClose() {
    return 'You have a long message typed. Are you sure you want to close?';
}

window.addEventListener('beforeunload', confirmClose, true);
```

I'm positive the script is running on the pages it should, but whenever I attempt to close the window, I don't receive any confirmation.

Comment: Known bug in Firefox.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5398772/firefox-4-onbeforeunload-custom-message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a security measure, [Firefox no longer allows pages to set a custom message for the `beforeunload` dialog.](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=588292) So, the `return` statement doesn't have any effect when using `addEventListener` (which you should).

To stop a page from unloading, you need to use `preventDefault()` like so:

```
window.addEventListener ('beforeunload', confirmClose, false);

function confirmClose (zEvent) {
    zEvent.preventDefault ();
}
```

This will throw up the unalterable dialog:

[image: Standard page-quit verification dialog]

If you want to display a custom message, you can do so with an ***extra*** dialog like so:

```
window.addEventListener ('beforeunload', confirmClose, false);

function confirmClose (zEvent) {
    var doQuitPage = confirm (
        "You have a long message typed. Are you sure you want to close?"
    );
    if ( ! doQuitPage) {
        zEvent.preventDefault ();
    }
}
```

But note two important annoyances:

1. If the user presses <kbd>OK</kbd>, then the page will exit with no further muss.
   But, if the user presses <kbd>Cancel</kbd>, then the *Are you sure* dialog will pop up and the user still must press <kbd>Stay on Page</kbd>.
2. Per the HTML5 spec, [future versions of Firefox might stop allowing `confirm()` during `beforeunload` events.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onbeforeunload#Notes)

Comment: This still isn't working for me. The lines I have 
`function confirmClose(evt) { evt.preventDefault(); }
    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', confirmClose, true);`

Comment: That works fine.  Something else is going on.  Try the code on a simpler page.  Link to the target page.  http://pastebin.com/ your actual complete script.