# how to show Warning message when user leaves the page without submitting the form

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, mozilla

Good day 
I want to show the warning message when user leaves the page with out submitting the form warning message should also be shown when user refreshes the page by pressing F5 
I have done 
When user presses F5 it shows warning message

```
$(function () {
    $(document).keydown(function (e) {
        if ((e.which || e.keyCode) == 116) {

            var FlagVal = $("#IsCaseInfoChanged").val();

            return "You have not saved your data. Do you really want to leave this page?";
        }
    });
});
```

And the below code shows warning message
1. Currently for "IE" browser and "Chrome" browser if u don't provide proper URL in address bar than its not giving warning message to user for valid URL its working fine. For Browser like Firefox and Safari its working in both condition.

And In Firefox browser it is giving browser specific warning message not our costume message. For other browser it is working fine. 
how do i resolve it.

```
 window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {

    /* Getting flag value for Browser if it has been set to true or not */

    /*if true show warning message*/

    var evtobj = window.event ? event : e;
    if (evtobj == e) {
        if (!evtobj.clientY) {
            return "You have not saved your data. Do you really want to leave this page?";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you provide your html?

Comment: html why ...........

Comment: I can work out with my local.

Comment: i will reduce the code remove the html element sorry

Comment: I have remove the html :)

Comment: Yes, am working. I got you error what you facing. am resolving it...

Comment: In case you are okay for plugin then [Are You Sure? - A light "dirty forms" JQuery Plugin](https://github.com/codedance/jquery.AreYouSure)

Comment: i have to trigger it right some where in my code

Comment: @Suraj If I get your question then you want something like [**onbeforeunload-custom-message**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5398772/firefox-4-onbeforeunload-custom-message), if **Yes**, then apologies! The previous mention plugin will also not work. Just tested it in Chrome & Firefox. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/x4o41ape/9/). And when I go thru the comment's, I don't see it's possible.

Comment: @kooky can i trigger this event in   window.onbeforeunload event based on my conditions

Comment: @kooky i have few drop downs which bind according to some conditions when i  load the page those drop down will get binded based on some conditions .so something has changed on the form now that event will be trigger that's  y i asked you can i trigger it in  window.onbeforeunload event

Comment: @Suraj I have posted

Comment: @Suraj let me know u got solution or hv to do?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try it, Am still working it only. But Just showing you the Idea

```
    function get_cookie ( cookie_name )
    {
        // http://www.thesitewizard.com/javascripts/cookies.shtml
        var cookie_string = document.cookie ;
        if (cookie_string.length != 0) {
            var cookie_value = cookie_string.match (
                            '(^|;)[\s]*' +
                            cookie_name +
                            '=([^;]*)' );
            return decodeURIComponent ( cookie_value[2] ) ;
        }
        return '' ;
    }

    $('document').ready(function(){
        var myCookie = get_cookie("validNavigationa");
        if (myCookie != null) {
            document.cookie = "validNavigationa=1";
        } else {
            document.cookie = "validNavigationa=2";
        }

        if(myCookie==2) {
            if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox")>0) {
                if(confirm("My Custom Message")) {

                    document.cookie = "validNavigationa=1";
                    //window.close();  This will change depends the firefox version
                    window.onbeforeunload = function() { document.cookie = "validNavigationa=1"; }
                } else {
                    window.stop();
                }
            } else {
                window.onbeforeunload = function() { return "R u okay to Restart"; }; 
            }
        }

        setTimeout(function(){
            document.cookie = "validNavigationa=2";
        },100);
    });
```

Comment: the custom message is coming even i am trying

Comment: Yes, while reload also I kept confirm message