# Unexpected behaviour of onbeforeunload handler/function in firefox 32.0.3 and IE

Tags: javascript, firefox, browser, confirm

I am trying to show a confirmation box when the user leaves the page and then use its returned value in **onbeforeunload** handler/function like

```
window.onbeforeunload = closingCode;
   function closingCode(){
   return confirm("You are leaving the page without saving some data. Do you want to continue?");
}
```

When this function is executed in the mentioned version of firefox, The window gets directly closed or refreshed without showing any confirmation dialog. I have tried to debug the script with firebug which shows that this function executes.

But when I use the code written below, A built-in browser confirmation dialog appears with a generic message.

```
window.onbeforeunload = closingCode;
       function closingCode(){
       return false;
    }
```

In Internet Explorer  8, the first code snippet results in two confirmation dialogs. One is mine and the other one is browser's default. whereas the the second snippet behaves the same.

I've tested this functionality here in stackoverflow, and found that It also shows a built-in confirmation dialog with the same generic message.

Is it possible to show a window.confirm() dialog, with desired message, in **onbeforeunload** handler/function or not? If yes, then kindly tell me how. Else, tell me why its not possible and provide some related links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onbeforeunload` handler is supposed to return a string. The browser will then display this message in a prompt.

```
function closingCode () {
    return "You are leaving the page without saving some data. Do you want to continue?";
}
```

Comment: In IE, the returned string is appearing with the generic message but in firefox, there is only a generic message.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5398772/firefox-4-onbeforeunload-custom-message

Comment: Thats what I want. Thanks a lot sir.