# Is there any way to show the custom message when exiting from the firefox browser

Tags: javascript, html

I want the script which can display the custom message to the user when it exits from the page in the firefox browser. Firefox is showing its default message even after using custom message, though chrome is showing it correctly. But i want to display this custom message in firefox also

```
 window.onbeforeunload = function() {

   return 'Are you sure.';
 }
```

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/333665/javascript-to-get-an-alert-when-closing-the-browser-window

Comment: I am asking for firefox, this message is displayed in chrome not in firefox , first check yourself. is really this message displays in firefox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears they disabled it on purpose: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload

> In Firefox 4 and later the returned string is not displayed to the user. Instead, Firefox displays the string "This page is asking you to confirm that you want to leave - data you have entered may not be saved."

See this related question for potential workarounds, but all are pretty messy:

[Firefox 4 onBeforeUnload custom message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5398772/firefox-4-onbeforeunload-custom-message)

Comment: But is there any way to hack this?

Comment: I only tried [the second answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9866486/2070057) in that linked question and it prompted the user with the custom message surrounded by default messaging like "this page is prompting etc..."  and followed up by their default prompt as well. So as far as I can tell even hacky solutions aren't going to improve this experience but maybe someone else will have a better solution.

Comment: It's a security issue. If you find a "hack", they'll fix it and the hack will stop working.